# Query Runs in Ms Access Database But Not When Executed From Application

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, oledb

Query with parameters works perfectly in ms access database. But when I supply  the same parameters from C# winforms application it returns no records.
If the parameter is passed to the query then it will use that parameter in where clause, otherwise it will retrieve all records.

bus table sample data:

[image]

Ms-Access Query:

```
PARAMETERS parPlateNo Text ( 255 );
SELECT bus.*
FROM bus
WHERE (((bus.plateNo) Like IIf(IsNull([parPlateNo]), True ,"%" & [parPlateNo] & "%")));
```

C# Code:

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(myGlobals.connString))
{
  using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter())
  {
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      cmd.CommandText = "qryBus";
      if(plateNo == "")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DBNull.Value);
      else
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", plateNo);

      adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
      dsDetails = new DataSet();
      adapter.Fill(dsDetails, "details");
    }
  }
}
```

PlateNo is a text column.

**Remarks**: If I remove the like statement in ms access query and run the same code in C#, it will run perfectly and retrieve all the records in table.

After that, I display the data in datagridview using bindingsource.

Why this is happening?

Comment: OleDB doesn't use named parameters.  It's index only.  My guess here is that you need to supply that parameter twice since you are using it twice.

Comment: How can I supply parameters without name?

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", plateNo);`  Repeat.  OleDB will just make a list of x number of parameters, and then supply those parameters with the x number of parameters you added.  They go in index order.

Comment: I tried cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", plateNo); but still no results. Should I repeat it multiple times?

Comment: Your query looks like it is using two parameter, so you need to add two values.  This is just my hunch.

Comment: It is same parameter but used twice

Comment: @CPerkins Not really.  It really does ignore anything that's written in there that's used as the "name" of the parameter.  That's why when you see a lot of OleDB query examples with parameters, you mostly see the name as just a question mark.  Order matters, names do not.

Comment: @HilalAl-Rajhi  The code which you show works on my setup.  LarsTech is correct that the name of the parameter does not matter.  It also works for me by specifying only one parameter.  Please update your question with more details around the code you posted.  How do you know that it does not work?  How are you inspecting the results?  Are you binding the dataset to a visual grid?  What does your data look like and what is a sample value of `plateNo`?  What is the dataype of `plateNo`?

Comment: @HilalAl-Rajhi  Also, why not make the WHERE expression more direct?  In the case of null parameter, don't waste effort comparing the [plateNo] column with itself.  Instead, use something like `WHERE IIf(IsNull([parPlateNo]),True,[bus].[plateNo] ALike "%" & [parPlateNo] & "%")`

Comment: This is beautiful suggestion Mr. C Perkins. I will update my question. I also tried using the ? mark but same result.

Comment: @HilalAl-Rajhi  Your updated code will NOT work if [parPlateNo] is Null... it would be like typing `bus.plateNo Like True` which makes no sense.  My edit shows the **`Iif` function as the outermost function**, not after the `LIKE` operator.  Also, LarsTech and I already mentioned that it doesn't matter if you use ? or a name for the parameter, so that should not matter.  Although you did update the code to explain the DataGridView binding, you did not show sample values for the `plateNo` variable, nor did you show sample data for the `bus.plateNo` column.

Comment: @HilalAl-Rajhi  **Have you tried loading a query that definitely returns data?**  In other words, temporarily remove the WHERE clause and change your query to `PARAMETERS parPlateNo Text ( 255 ); SELECT bus.* FROM bus;`    Does that show results?

Comment: Yes, it runs perfectly

Comment: Sorry, I have no other suggestions.  As I said, the original code was working for me.  I suspect that you may have an issue with updated bindings after retrieving the data.  But now that you have changed the original SQL many times (and it is now incorrect) and that you still have not shown ALL relevant code and sample data, I'm at a loss.

Comment: Original code you mean C# code?

Comment: Am sorry for changing my code Mr. C Perkins. Its that I need to make sure that the suggested solution does not work with me.

Answer (score 0):

You using oleDB. You have to change that query and use % as wild cards. DAO, and native Access you use *, but for ADO, or oleDB, you have to use % as the wild cards.

Comment: You are right. I edited the question and tried it but actually leading to the same results. No error but empty records

Comment: I would remove the parameters from the query, and just add them in your .net code. This will also allow you to use + add conditions for any column, not just what the original query was defined for. So, just place your sql against that query with the @parms in your .net code.

Comment: @HilalAl-Rajhi  How do you know that he's right if your code still does not work?  Replacing the wildcard presents a new problem that the query now does not work within Access.  Instead, an alternative that works for both native Access DAO and ADO, OleDB is the operator `Alike` with `%` for wildcards.  This way the query works in all contexts: `bus.plateNo ALike "%" & [parPlateNo] & "%"`

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of examples that should help you get this up and running.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=Your_Server_Name;Database=AdventureWorksLT2012;Trusted_Connection=True"); 

            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [dbo].[Student] values(@a,@b,@c)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", textBox3.Text);
                con.Open();
                a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (a > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Submited");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

        }
```

AND

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server=Your_Server_Name;Database=AdventureWorksLT2012;Trusted_Connection=True"); 

            try
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from student where sid=@a", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",int.Parse(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
                con.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    if (dr.Read())
                    {
                        textBox1.Text = dr["sid"].ToString();
                        textBox2.Text = dr["fname"].ToString();
                        textBox3.Text = dr["lname"].ToString();
                        //label1.Text = dr["cdate"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```